# Ошибка после выполнения цикла while с использованием ifstream read

Tags: c++

Не могу понять в чем ошибка по сути все работает но try catch выдает мне ошибку что цикл завершен не верно.

**2.bin** хранит запись в бинарном виде просто цифры по порядку, записаны через ofstream

Пример кода

```
int a;
try
{
    ifstream in;
    in.exceptions(ifstream::badbit | ifstream::failbit | ifstream::eofbit);
    in.open("2.bin", ios::binary);

    while (in.read((char*)& a, sizeof a)) // я думаю ошибка где то тут
    {
        cout << a << endl;
        // когда цикл завершит последнее вычисления
        // он выходит нормально, вроде как, но сразу попадает в catch
    }
    cout << "работает" << endl; // если не сработало значит не работает
}
catch (const exception& ex) // вот прямо сюда
{
    cout << ex.what() << endl;
    // ошибка 1
}
catch (...)
{
    // критическая ошибка 2
}
```

По сути все выполняется правильно но почему при завершении цикла меня кидает в catch я не понял.

Comment: он ничего не показывает мне, даже пустой файл 2.bin вызывает ошибку внутри цикла

Comment: смысл `exceptions` в том, чтобы не проверять результаты вызова каждой функции отдельно. С выставленным `ifstream::eofbit` при достижении конца файла будет выброшено исключение. При чтении из бинарного файла имеет смысл использовать какой-то формат с указанием количества читаемых элементов.

Comment: @VTT а как тогда посоветуете сделать лучше?
Даже если удалить `eofbit` он все равно выдает ошибку
`ios_base::failbit set: iostream stream error`

Comment: Может есть способ заменить цикл обычным кодом?
Но тогда как достать все варианты особенно если это будет векторный массив.

Comment: Ну можно не использовать исключения, а проверять результаты функций

Comment: у меня было раньше через if else но я бы хотел проверять абсолютно все ошибки.

Comment: @VTT что если использовать бесконечный цикл `for`, можно как то реализовать пока не закончит считать все массивы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы написали `in.exceptions(... | ifstream::eofbit);`
и читаете поток пока он не закончится `while (in.read(...))`
Поток заканчивается и бросается исключение. Всё как Вы и просили.

Comment: А как мне тогда поставить, если мне нужно проверять на ошибки и что бы работал мой цикл?

Comment: так он работает нормально
`while (a < 4)
{
    cout << a << endl;
    a++
}`

Comment: Отдал вам галочку раз нету решения.